# I need Help at making a responsive menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

So i want to make this responsive menu. On Desktop it looks like this:

[image]

And on Mobile it should look stacked overlapping everything under it but not pushing it down. So not like this:

(Before button pressed)

[image]

(After button pressed)

[image]

You can see that the Slideshow below is pushed down and the obvious misplacement of the menu on the button in general.

Plese help me to fix this, im a poor backend dev.
Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("menu");
    if (x.className === "menu") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "menu";
    }
}
```

```css
.menu .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 965px) {
    .menu a {display: none;}
    .menu a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  
  /* The "responsive" class is added to the menu with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon */
@media screen and (max-width: 965px) {
    .menu.responsive {
        background-color: white;
        position: relative;
    }
    .menu.responsive a.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        }
    .menu.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="mainheader">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="../bilder/Logo_Koeln_Fliesen_Esch.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu" class="menu">
                        <a href="start.html">Unternehmen</a>
                        <a href="start.html">Leistungen</a>
                        <a href="referenzen.html">Referenzen</a>
                        <a href="start.html">Kontakt</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                            <img class="bigicon"  src="../bilder/menu.png">
                        </a>    
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Try setting the div bar (the white bar)'s position to absolute. That way, the bar shouldn't stretch. Also, set the opened burger menu's z-index higher, so it would appear in front of the three lines.

Comment: Setting the menu position to absolute will fix the issue with the stretch but not the overlapping af the button. z-index is not an option because the button should be accessible. *i did set absolut and right 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the anwer to fix the issue was to **set the responsive menu class to absolute**, also you have to use **right: 0;** so it stays in place.
After that i figured out that i could just move the menu links down since they are also absolute now in order to prevent them from overlapping the button.

Thanks for the effort of helping everyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("menu");
    if (x.className === "menu") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "menu";
    }
}
```

```css
.menu .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 965px) {
    .menu a {display: none;}
    .menu a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  
  /* The "responsive" class is added to the menu with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon */
@media screen and (max-width: 965px) {
    .menu.responsive {
        background-color: white;
        position: relative;
    }
 
    .menu.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: right
    }
}
```

```html
                       <img src="../bilder/Logo_Koeln_Fliesen_Esch.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu" class="menu">
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">  <img class="bigicon"  src="../bilder/menu.png"> </a>
                                            <span>
                        <a href="start.html">Unternehmen</a>
                        <a href="start.html">Leistungen</a>
                        <a href="referenzen.html">Referenzen</a>
                        <a href="start.html">Kontakt</a>
</span>
                          
                          
                    </div>
                </div>
```

with out looking at whole page code here is what you need to do or something I would always check before going forward.

1. for css to work properly add this meta tag in head `<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui, height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`
2. secondly menu is something that should be stacked higher up on the interactive and display layer so it does not mess with other elements on the page. One way of doing this is to place the tag at the bottom of everything last on page (remember to css absolute positioning on the menu div) or zoom it up like +10000 should do.
3. please try not to add responsiveness after the fact like when user clicks this will create whole lot of problem going forward as computed vs initial values collide. Leave things to css as much as possible. It is good code from w3school follow its instructions as stated.
4. For the positioning issue calculate height of the image;
5. it is actually your icon that is being positioned every thing else is relative to where it should be. so move your icon as first item then every other anchor tag below it. this should solve your positioning issue.

Comment: When you play with positioning too much it creates unintended results.  All i did was move your icon link to top and encapsulated everything else in another span result as i stated. PS i had spent weeks trying to perfect the w3Schools example you are tying to advance upon.

Comment: The css works properly, the meta tags are added in this example. It has to do with the positioning and stuff. "absolut" fixes at least one of the issues. I will try some of the other advice tomorrow. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

Add `z-index` property to .menu.responsive class.

Comment: wont fix the fundemantal issues. By just adding a z-index, the navbar would still be displayed above the menu button and as such the menu wont be able to get closed. as you cant reach the button anymore.

Comment: tacoshy is rigth on this one, but still thx for the answer